# How to fix application crash in for-loop using an array

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop

my question might be different than the title. I have an Edittext which is "visibility.Gone" by default:

## Xml file:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edit5"
android:layout_width="203dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="edit5"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:gravity="center"
android:visibility="gone" />
```

There is a button named "increasebtn" which makes the edittext visible when clicked:

```
if (edit5.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        edit6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        edit5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and I have a for-loop which prints some strings in a textview:

```
String editt1 = edit1.getText().toString();
                    String editt2 = edit2.getText().toString();
                    String editt3 = edit3.getText().toString();
                    String editt4 = edit4.getText().toString();
                    String editt5 = edit5.getText().toString();


                    String[] names = {editt2, editt1, editt3, editt4};
                    List<String> namesstr = Arrays.asList(names);
                    Collections.shuffle(namesstr);
                    names = namesstr.toArray(new String[namesstr.size()]);


                    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i = i + 2) {
                        text.append(names[i] + " with " + names[i + 1]);

                    }
                    textView.setText(text.toString());
```

These codes are fine and the result is this:

> Kim with Sam
>   John with Edison

## THE PROBLEM IS

when I add my VISIBLE(not invisible) to my String called "names" the application crashes. the problem is not with

```
String editt5 = edit5.getText().toString();
```

It's this:

```
String[] names = {editt2, editt1, editt3, editt4,editt5};
```

when I add the "editt5" to the string the app crashes :(

Comment: stacktrace of the exception could help.

Comment: Maybe, since you are adding editt5 but not editt6, when the value for i=5 in the for loop it tries to get the slot 6 in the array (i+1), which doesn't exists, and that is why you get the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are 4 items in `names`, then this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i = i + 2) {
    text.append(names[i] + " with " + names[i + 1]);
}
```

appends to the `StringBuilder`:

```
names[0] + " with " + names[1]
names[2] + " with " + names[3]
```

which works, but if there are 5 items, it will try to append:

```
names[0] + " with " + names[1]
names[2] + " with " + names[3]
names[4] + " with " + names[5]
```

but there is not `names[5]` since the last item's index is `4` and your app crashes.
 You must have even number of items in `names` to apply this loop, unless you want something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
    text.append(names[i] + " with " + names[i + 1]);
}
```

which will give you this:

```
names[0] + " with " + names[1]
names[1] + " with " + names[2]
names[2] + " with " + names[3]
names[3] + " with " + names[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because you are getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Why? Because when you have 5 elements inside of the array like this

```
String[] names = {editt2, editt1, editt3, editt4,editt5};
```

then after the second loop `i` becomes 4 which is the actual length of `names`. But inside of the loop, you are trying to get `names[i + 1]` which is `names[5]`.

Array index starts from 0 so `names[5]` would mean 6th element. But you don't have it and it is causing the crash.